# Draw_grapviz : Missing Python dependency error

Tags: python, biopython, pygraphviz

Im trying to create a phylogenetic tree using the `Phylo.draw_graphviz` method from the `BioPython` and `PyGraphviz` library. I read the docs and installed `networkx`, `matplotlib` as well as `Graphviz 2.38` for windows. I then installed `PyGraphviz` from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz) . I followed the following piece of code given in [Biopython wiki](http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo#Bootstrap_Methods):

```
from Bio import Phylo
import pylab

tree = Phylo.read('allseqs.dnd', 'newick')
Phylo.draw_graphviz(tree)
pylab.show()
```

However I keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GAMER\Desktop\Methybase\Data\Helicobacter  pylori  F16\graphtezt.py", line 5, in <module>
    Phylo.draw_graphviz(tree)
  File "c:\users\gamer\desktop\padai\coding\user\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\_utils.py", line 155, in draw_graphviz
    raise MissingPythonDependencyError(
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'MissingPythonDependencyError' referenced before assignment
```

The source code is available [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo._utils-pysrc.html#draw_graphviz). I checked line `155` as the traceback suggested and this is what it says:

```
raise MissingPythonDependencyError( 
                 "Install PyGraphviz or pydot if you want to use draw_graphviz.")
```

Any solution will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems from looking at the code on that link that there is a crucial line missing. This should be `from Bio import MissingPythonDependencyError` and it should appear indented and between line 154 and line 155. The problem is that the function has not been imported before it is called, as it is only imported on line 134 if the module networkx is missing.

Comment: I tried editing the code and adding in the `import` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: That's is strange, I would have expected it to throw an exception. but for it not to be the same one. Are you sure that the error is exactly the same?

Comment: Yes I still get the same error. Whats even more confusing is that after I add the `import` , the `raise..` statement at 155 goes to 156 but the error still shows that the error is at lien 155 at the `raise...`

Comment: It seems from that that the interpreter is caching the module. In fact I am almost certain as the line number corresponds to what used to be on that line that something needs reloading. Have any files ending in .pyc or .pyo appeared?

Comment: I tried commenting out the `raise`. Same error. How can it give me an error on a comment?

Comment: @letsc make sure you've deleted any `.pyc` files after saving your changes and before running them.

Comment: @MattDMo - I did. There are no `.pyc` files created

Comment: Are you on python3 or python2? In python3 you'll have a folder called `__pycache__` with the `.pyc` files in it.

Comment: I am using `python 2.7`